# Lint/Syntax: class definition in method body Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubocop

Please I have installed Ruby 3.1.2 and using rubocop  1.34.1 (using Parser 3.1.2.1, rubocop-ast 1.21.0, running on ruby 3.1.2 x86_64-linux)
My code is:

```
    require "./person.rb"

class Teacher < Person

  def initialize(name: "Unknow", age, specialization)
    super(name, age)
    @specialization = specialization
  end

  def can_use_services?
    true
  end
end
```

And when I run rubocop it shows the following offenses:

```
classes/teacher.rb:3:1: E: Lint/Syntax: class definition in method body
(Using Ruby 3.2 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)
class Teacher < Person
^^^^^
classes/teacher.rb:5:34: E: Lint/Syntax: unexpected token tIDENTIFIER
(Using Ruby 3.2 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)
  def initialize(name: "Unknow", age, specialization)
                                 ^^^
classes/teacher.rb:5:53: E: Lint/Syntax: unexpected token tRPAREN
(Using Ruby 3.2 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)
  def initialize(name: "Unknow", age, specialization)
                                                    ^
classes/teacher.rb:13:1: E: Lint/Syntax: unexpected token kEND
(Using Ruby 3.2 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)
end
^^^
```

Comment: There is no question in your question. What is your question? Also, please make sure that you only ask a *single* question per question. And, please make sure that you include *all* the code required to reproduce your problem in the question, but *only the minimum amount of code* required.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html);

> There are three types of arguments when sending a message, the
> positional arguments, keyword (or named) arguments and the block
> argument. Each message sent may use one, two or all types of
> arguments, but the arguments must be supplied in this order.

So, in your example, the keyword argument `name` should be after the positional ones (`age`, `specialization`). If you move it at the end then it should work.

```
class Teacher < Person
  def initialize(age, specialization, name: "Unknow")
    super(name, age)
    @specialization = specialization
  end

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add in your `.rubocop.yml` file

```yaml
AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 3.1
```

and afterwards it will show more detailed rubocop errors of your code.